# Almost complex structures on real Lie groups

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be an even-dimensional Lie group, and let $\mathfrak{g}$ be its Lie algebra. I want to explore when a complex structure on $\mathfrak{g}$ induces a complex structure on $G$ making it into a complex Lie group.

To begin with, let's investigate when an almost complex structure $I$ on $G$ makes it into a complex Lie group. First of all, $I$ must be integrable. Next, we want the multiplication $m \colon G \times G \to G$ to be holomorphic (it is a standard fact that the inverse $i \colon G \to G$ will then also be holomorphic). The differential of $m$ can be expressed via the differentials of left and right translations:

$$
\text{d}m_{(g,h)} = \text{d}(R_h)_g \, \oplus \text{d}(L_g)_h \, \colon \; T_g G \oplus T_h G \, \to \, T_{gh} G,
$$

so it suffices to require that left and right translations are holomorphic. But this means exactly that $I$ is bi-invariant. So, we are looking for integrable bi-invariant almost complex structures on $G$.

Next, we have the evaluation-at-the-identity map

$$
\left\{ \begin{aligned} &\text{bi-invariant integrable} \\ &\text{almost complex structures on} \, G \\ \end{aligned} \right\} \longrightarrow \left\{ \begin{aligned} &\text{complex} \\ &\text{structures on} \, \mathfrak{g} \\ \end{aligned} \right\},
$$

which is obviously injective. Let $J$ be a complex structure on $\mathfrak{g}$. If it lies in the image of this map, it must come from $J^L$ (the left-invariant almost complex structure on $G$ corresponding to $J \,$: $\, J^L_g = \text{d}(L_g)_e \circ J \circ \text{d}(L_{g^{-1}})_g$; the right-invariant one will be denoted by $J^R$). One can easily come up with necessary and sufficient conditions on $J$ to lie in the image of the map above:

1. $[X, Y] + J[JX, Y] + J[X, JY] - [JX, JY] = 0 \,$ for all $X, Y \in \mathfrak{g}$. This is nothing but vanishing of the Nijenhuis tensor of $J^L$, which is equivalent to the integrability of $J^L$.
2. $J^L$ is bi-invariant, i.e. $J^L = J^R$. This can be reformulated as follows: $J$ commutes with $\text{Ad}(g)$ for all $\, g \in G$.

But there is another obvious necessary condition:

3. The Lie bracket of $\mathfrak{g}$ is $\mathbb{C}$-bilinear with respect to $J$, which is equivalent to $[X, JY] = J[X, Y] \,$ for all $X, Y \in \mathfrak{g}$, which, in turn, is equivalent to the condition that $J$ commutes with $\text{ad}(X)$ for any $X \in \mathfrak{g}$.

The first two conditions are necessary and sufficient, so $(1, 2) \Rightarrow (3)$. One can also observe that $(3) \Rightarrow (1)$.

**Claim.** If $G$ is connected, then $(3) \Rightarrow (2)$.

Indeed, $(3)$ implies that $J$ makes $\mathfrak{g}$ into a complex Lie algebra. Let us write $\mathfrak{g}_J$ when $\mathfrak{g}$ is regarded as a complex Lie algebra. We have a complex Lie group $\text{GL}(\mathfrak{g}_J)$ and its closed complex Lie subgroup $\text{Aut}(\mathfrak{g}_J)$. The former is a closed real Lie subgroup of $\text{GL}(\mathfrak{g})$. We also have a closed real Lie subgroup $\text{Aut}(\mathfrak{g})$ of $\text{GL}(\mathfrak{g})$ such that $\text{Aut}(\mathfrak{g}) \cap \text{GL}(\mathfrak{g}_J) = \text{Aut}(\mathfrak{g}_J)$. We have a morphism of real Lie groups $\text{Ad} \colon G \to \text{Aut}(\mathfrak{g})$. The induced morphism of Lie algebras is $\text{ad} \colon \mathfrak{g} \to \text{Der}(\mathfrak{g})$. But $(3)$ implies that the image of $\text{ad}$ lies in $Der(\mathfrak{g}_J)$, which is the Lie algebra of $\text{Aut}(\mathfrak{g}_J) \subseteq \text{Aut}(\mathfrak{g})$. Connectedness of $G$ implies that the image of $\text{Ad}$ lies in $\text{Aut}(\mathfrak{g}_J)$, so we are done.

We obtain that $(1, 2) \Leftrightarrow (3)$ for connected Lie groups, so we end up with the following conclusion:

> If $G$ is a connected even-dimensional Lie group with a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, then a complex structure $J$ on $\mathfrak{g}$ induces a complex structure on $G$ making it into a complex Lie group if and only if the Lie bracket on $\mathfrak{g}$ is $\mathbb{C}$-bilinear with respect to $J$.

Condition $(3)$ looks significantly easier to check, so here is my question:

> Does this conclusion remain true for non-connected Lie groups?

Comment: No, take $\mathbf{R}^2\rtimes \mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$ acting as a reflection. You need at least to assume that the whole adjoint representation of $G$ preserves the complex structure on $\mathfrak{g}$.

Comment: @YCor, thanks again, this is a very simple but elegant counterexample. Indeed, other connected components may add to the adjoint representation of $G$ in a way unnoticeable by its differential.